# Cloudflare is able to fetch all my domain CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, cloudflare

Today, I was in the process of setting up an account with Cloudflare (the free tier). During the setup, it asked for the domain I wanted to configure. When I introduced my domain, and without making any changes to my DNS provider's configuration (which is hosted on AWS Route53), Cloudflare retrieved a full list of all DNS records, including CNAME records that were recently created. However, when I use tools like dig, I can't get any CNAME record responses.

I'm curious to understand how Cloudflare is able to fetch this list of CNAME records, especially when I haven't made them my authoritative DNS provider.

Comment: Do these records all have SSL certificates? If so, they might be using the Certificate Transparency logs.

Comment: the CNAME use a wildcard certificate. I use cloudflare dns in my computer (1.1.1.1) maybe they fetch this data?